# how find this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}⁡\frac{x^2+1}{\cos x-1}$

My solution is:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+1}{\cos x-}\frac{\cos x+1}{\cos x+1}$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x^2+1)(\cos x+1)}{\cos^2 x-1}$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x^2+1)(\cos x+1)}{-(1-\cos^2 x)}$

Since $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x^2+1)(\cos x+1)}{-\sin^2 x}$

I'm stuck here. What next?

Comment: Is the starting problem $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^2+1}{\cos x-1}$?

Comment: yes it is , sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no indeterminatation,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+1}{\cos x-1}=\frac{1}{0^-}=-\infty $$

Answer (score 0):

This Limit doesn't exist! Notice that as $x\to 0$, $x^2+1 \to 1$ and $\cos x-1 \to 0$; So the Limit $\to -\infty.$